# What is a cinammyl system?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I came across this term while searching for reference in *March's Advanced Organic Chemistry*.

It said:

> LAH gives significant double reduction only in cinammyl systems, for example, with PhCH=CHCOOH.

This term is new for me and Google didn't have any  specific result for this.

Comment: Cinnamyl is the non-systematic name for the PhCH=CHCH2X system where X is a heteroatom, most frequently O or halogen

Comment: The structure you've provided is cinnamic acid.. now what do you think?